# unknown column in 'where clause' date

Tags: mysql

The query below returns what I look for.

```
SELECT * from meetings where meetings.date = '2018-03-12';
```

However, the one below is giving me

> Unknown column '‘2018' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT roomNumber 
FROM rooms 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT *
FROM meetings 
WHERE rooms.roomNumber = meetings.room
AND meetings.date = ‘2018-03-12’ );
```

I tried 2018-03-12 without single quotes, and it works. However, that does not return the right set of records. I am looking for available rooms that do not have a meeting on that day.

Comment: In the query that does not work you appear to have "smart" quotes around the date. Look closely atthe error message. The 2 quotes after `column` aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT roomNumber 
FROM rooms 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT *
FROM meetings 
WHERE rooms.roomNumber = meetings.room
AND meetings.date = '2018-03-12' );
```

This is essentially the correction @BoarGules commented with, you are using smart quotes : `‘2018-03-12’` instead of single quotes: `'2018-03-12'`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT roomNumber 
FROM rooms 
WHERE NOT EXISTS IN 
( SELECT rooms.roomNumber
FROM meetings 
WHERE rooms.roomNumber = meetings.room
AND meetings.date = 2018-03-12 );
```

try with this query

Comment: Date strings have to be wrapped in single quotes, otherwise you would perform mathematical subtraction with the provided integers (your code would equal `meetings.date=2003`)